# What is the meaning of "Parries" in "Choose $\delta > 0$ such that $\delta$ parries $\varepsilon$ for this uniform continuity of $f$.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, epsilon-delta

I'm reading through a probability text and it uses the term "parries" in an epsilon / delta proof.  I've never seen this word used before and I certainly don't understand what it is supposed to mean.  Here is the verbiage:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$, we thus need to show $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(|f(x_n) − f(x)| > \varepsilon) = 0$.  To this end, let $m \geq 1$. As $[−(m + 1), m + 1]$ is compact, $f$ is uniformly continuous on this set. Choose $\delta > 0$ such that $\delta$ **parries** $\varepsilon$ for this uniform continuity of $f$ ...

What does "Choose $\delta > 0$ such that $\delta$ parries $\varepsilon$..." mean exactly?

Thank you.

Comment: It means: $\delta$ satisfies whatever it needs to in the definition of "uniform continuity".  I guess that guy is using "sword-fighting" language to make the definition vivid.  A positive number $\epsilon$ is the **strike** at you by your opponent, and the number $\delta$ you have to come up with in response is your **parry**.

Comment: It just means delta satisfies the uniform continuity definition instantiated for that particular $\varepsilon$. This "game" analogy can be useful for thinking about forall-exists quantifiers.

Comment: That's awesome. Whoever the author of this text is, they're living in 3018.